# Show the sequence is decreasing

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am supposed to show the sequence is decreasing for $0<r \leqslant 1$:
$$
\left\{\frac{r^{n}}{n}\right\}
$$

I used:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}<1 \rightarrow r\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right) \leqslant 1 $$

But how do I state it's true for $\leqslant 1 $ and how do I show the other part of the inequality -  the lower bound is $0$:  ($0<r$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n\in\Bbb N$, then $r^{n+1}<r^n$ and $\frac1{n+1}<\frac1n$; therefore, $\frac{r^{n+1}}{n+1}<\frac{r^n}n$.

And, given $\varepsilon>0$, take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $N\geqslant\frac1\varepsilon$. Then$$n\geqslant N\implies\frac{r^n}n\leqslant\frac1n\leqslant\frac1N\leqslant\varepsilon.$$